# Change server_uuid in MySQL

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication, my.cnf

I want to know if there is any way to update server_uuid; I am trying master-slave replication, and I need different server_uuid.

FYI - I don't have server_uuid in my my.cnf file, and when I update it like this:

`mysql> SET GLOBAL server_uuid = '1';`

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'server_uuid' is a read only variable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the error.

In the data_dir, there is an auto.cnf file. Stop the mysql service, remove that file (take a backup, if needed), and then start the service; It will generate a new auto.cnf file, which will be different than the master server.